# cElementTree insatall in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

How to install **cElementTree** on **Ubuntu** where **python 2.7** is present,

**Need Version 1.0.5**

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:32:47) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cElementTree
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cElementTree
```

**sudo pip install cElementTree**

```
root@imp-vivek:/home/# sudo pip install cElementTree
Downloading/unpacking cElementTree
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement cElementTree
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for cElementTree
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: Did you try `sudo pip install cElementTree` from bash?

Comment: ye, not working

Comment: It doesn't look like a problem of yours. I have tried the same command (even detailing the version `pip install -Iv cElementTree==1.0.5`) and I've received the same error message. The reason is that asociated URL `https://pypi.python.org/simple/cElementTree/` is empty (at least at this moments).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://effbot.org/zone/celementtree.htm

cElementTree is included with Python 2.5 and later, as xml.etree.cElementTree.

You can make a 'manual' installation from the sources available on the website.

Comment: for "ImportError: No module named elementtree" ??

Comment: Download the archive :

Comment: and then install  $ sudo python setup.py install